# Localizing buttons in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, pseudolocalization

This is my first question so far so I would love some understanding!

I am localizing entire application. I have no problem with labels that while pseudolocation translate properly. However, trying to achieve the same with buttons it doesn't work.

The code is

```
 [self.Clear setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Clear",nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and the .string file in en.plist content looks like this

```
 "Clear" = "Blah";
```

The pseudolocation doesn't work and I would really appreciate some help. The simulator keeps showing Clear.

If you have any questions regarding this, I will answer!

Please don't eat me :P

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, you can set 4 strings, one for each of the states in the "State Config" dropdown.

OR, alternatively, in code, you set the button title for each state:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"21.title", @"Norm!")    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"21.title-highlighted", @"hi btn") forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"21.title-selected", @"sel btn") forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"21.title-disabled", @"dis btn") forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Courtsey : [Localize IOS button label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668299/localize-ios-button-label)

Comment: Unfortunately trying to implement all the different states of the button and pseudolocalizing them did not work. The button still shows "Calculate"