# How to localize UIButton's attributed title?

Tags: ios, localization

Usually when text is plain I can localize it like this:

```
"cX3-mQ-HQE.normalTitle" = "arabic.request_again";
```

and it works, but my `UIButton` has attributed title and it doesn't work any more with above. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Cough ** NSLocalizedString**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Localize IOS button label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668299/localize-ios-button-label)

Comment: it may be impossible by using storyboard localization. you must have to set using programmmatically.